# Are there NP languages whose verification is P-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory

A decision problem is in NP if a candidate "yes" can be verified in polynomial time.

Are there decision problems whose "yes" is verified with an algorithm that is P-complete (reducible in logspace)? Are those problems in NP?

If so, can the "yes" be verified in logspace?

I'm told "[for every NP language we can find a verifier that uses only logspace](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/125293/41511)."

Answer (score 3):

Every language in NP has a logspace verifier.

Indeed, let $L$ be any language in NP. Therefore, there is a polynomial time machine $T$ and a polynomial $p$ such that $x \in L$ iff some string $y$ of size at most $p(|x|)$ makes $T(x,y)$ accept.

While the witness $y$ may be hard to check, we can make help a logspace machine verify it by including the *transcript* of the accepting computation. We construct another machine $T'$ which accepts a new witness $z$. The witness $z$ consists of a sequence of configurations of the machine $T$, starting with an initial configuration encoding $x$ and $y$, and ending at an accepting configuration. Since each configuration has polynomial length, a logspace machine can verify that $z$ indeed consists of a valid sequence of configurations.

Comment: When T is a verifier we can design it so that it only accepts valid certificates y. But when T (or its sequence of states) is part of a witness z, it can be anything and T' then needs to check that T is not some random but valid sequence that accepts a bogus certificate y. Can T' be designed in that way?

Comment: The machine $T$ is fixed ahead of time. It is hard-coded inside $T’$.